# canvas matrix setTransform with pivot

Tags: canvas, matrix, transform

I made affine transform like under code.

```
   /**
   * @description getAffineTransform using SRT
   * @param {Number} xScale xScale
   * @param {Number} yScale yScale
   * @param {Number} radian radian
   * @param {Point} position position
   * @param {Point} pivot pivot
   * @return {CanvasMatrix} CanvasMatrix
   * @member CoordinateSystem#getAffineTransform
   */
  getAffineTransform(xScale, yScale, radian, position, pivot) {
    let a, b, c, d;
    let matrix = new CanvasMatrix();

    // origin to pivot
    if (pivot) {
      matrix = matrix.multiply(new CanvasMatrix(1, 0, 0, 1, pivot.x, pivot.y));
    }

    // Scale
    matrix = matrix.multiply(new CanvasMatrix(xScale, 0, 0, yScale, 0, 0));

    // Rotate
    if (this._opt.orientation === ORIENTATION.CCW) {
      a = Math.cos(radian);
      b = -Math.sin(radian);
      c = Math.sin(radian);
      d = Math.cos(radian);
    } else {
      a = Math.cos(radian);
      b = Math.sin(radian);
      c = -Math.sin(radian);
      d = Math.cos(radian);
    }
    matrix = matrix.multiply(new CanvasMatrix(a, b, c, d, 0, 0));

    // Translate
    matrix = matrix.multiply(new CanvasMatrix(1, 0, 0, 1, position.x, position.y));

    // pivot to origin'
    if (pivot) {
      matrix = matrix.multiply(new CanvasMatrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -pivot.x, -pivot.y));
    }

    return matrix;
  }
```

It work very well without moving pivot.
But if I move old pivot to new pivot, it doesn't works.
It is reset by new pivot.
How can I remain old pivot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 2D matrix

The function you have is overly complex with 6 matrix to get one plus all the multiplications is a lot of work for a single transform.

2D matrix are best handled in one go

```
// radian is negative if CCW
// Pivot and position do not effect the first 4 of the matrix a,b,c,d
// xScale and yScale only effect the x and y axis respectively so can be combine 
// with the rotation
// Returns matrix as a 6 item array [a,b,c,d,e,f]
function getAffineTransform(xScale, yScale, radian, position, pivot){
    const m = [  // m for matrix
         Math.cos(radian) * xScale,
         Math.sin(radian) * xScale,
        -Math.sin(radian) * yScale,
         Math.cos(radian) * yScale,
    ];
    m[4] = pivot.x - position.x * m[0] - position.y * m[2];
    m[5] = pivot.y - position.x * m[1] - position.y * m[3];
    return m;
}
```

Though I am not sure what you mean by pivot (assuming it the rotation point) and position is the offset from that.

If the other way around then swap on last two lines before return.

I find that understanding the 2D transform is best to think of the values `a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`e`,`f` as vector defining scale and direction of x axis (a,b) vector defining scale and direction of y axis (c,d) and coordinate of origin (e,f)

Thus the transform identity is 1,0 (x axis) 0,1 (y axis) and 0,0 (origin), to scale by 2 is 2,0,0,2,0,0 to rotate 90 CW is 0,2,-2,0,0,0

### Example use sliders to change transform

```js
const ctx = can.getContext("2d");
function getAffineTransform(xScale, yScale, radian, position, pivot){
    const m = [  // m for matrix
         Math.cos(radian) * xScale,
         Math.sin(radian) * xScale,
        -Math.sin(radian) * yScale,
         Math.cos(radian) * yScale,
    ];
    m[4] = pivot.x - position.x * m[0] - position.y * m[2];
    m[5] = pivot.y - position.x * m[1] - position.y * m[3];
    return m;
}
const vals = {
    XScale : 1,
    YScale : 1,
    PosX : 0,
    PosY : 0,
    PivX : 0,
    PivY : 0,
    Rot : 0,
}
const props = Object.keys(vals);
const mouse = { down : false };
inputs.addEventListener("mousedown",()=>mouse.down = true);
inputs.addEventListener("mouseup",()=>mouse.down = false);
inputs.addEventListener("mousemove",()=>{
    if(mouse.down){
        updateDom();
    }
})

function updateDom(){
    props.forEach(key => { window["el"+key].textContent = vals[key] = Number(window["in"+ key].value); })
    drawBox()
}
function setupDom(){
    props.forEach(key => { window["el"+key].textContent = window["in"+ key].value = vals[key]; })
    drawBox()

}


function drawBox(){
    if(can.width !== innerWidth || can.height !== innerHeight){
        can.width = innerWidth;
        can.height = innerHeight;
    }
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,innerWidth,innerHeight);
    const mat = getAffineTransform(
        vals.XScale,
        vals.YScale,
        vals.Rot,
        {x : vals.PosX, y: vals.PosY},
        {x : vals.PivX, y: vals.PivY}
    );
    ctx.setTransform(mat[0],mat[1],mat[2],mat[3],mat[4],mat[5]);
    ctx.strokeRect(0,0,100,100);
    ctx.strokeRect(vals.PosX-2,vals.PosY-2,4,4);

}
setupDom();
```

```css
canvas {
    position : absolute;
    top : 0px;
    left : 0px;
    z-index : -10;
}
```

```html
<canvas id=can></canvas>
<div id="inputs">
<div><input id=inXScale type=range min=0.1 max=3 step=0.1></input><span id=elXScale></span> xScale</div>
<div><input id=inYScale type=range min=0.1 max=3 step=0.1></input><span id=elYScale></span> yScale</div>
<div><input id=inPosX type=range min=0 max=100></input><span id=elPosX></span> pos X</div>
<div><input id=inPosY type=range min=0 max=100></input><span id=elPosY></span> pos Y</div>
<div><input id=inPivX type=range min=0 max=500></input><span id=elPivX></span> pivot X</div>
<div><input id=inPivY type=range min=0 max=500></input><span id=elPivY></span> pivot Y</div>
<div><input id=inRot type=range  min=0 max=13 step=0.1></input><span id=elRot></span> rotate</div>
</div>
```

Comment: My guess is by pivot he ment pre-translation